# Echo in php Post block is not printing out values posted by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a test that runs for a certain number of trials, and once finished, it posts the data to the PHP script. The data is successfully added to the database, but it does not echo out the results. I want the test results to be displayed for the user.

PHP

```
<?php
    require_once 'php-includes/header.php';
    include ('php-includes/phpValidate.php');
    if ($_POST) {
        include ('php-includes/antHelper.php');

        $testData = removeDelimiters($_POST['RT'], $_POST['condition'], $_POST['response'], $_POST['ansStr'], $_POST['congruency'], $_POST['cueStr']);
        $testID = addTest($_POST['toa'], $_POST['nTrial']);

        if (isset($testID)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($testData["RT"]); $i++) {
                addResponse((int)$testData["RT"][$i], (int)$testData["condition"][$i], $testData["response"][$i], $testData["answer"][$i], $testData["cue"][$i], $testData["congruence"][$i], $testID);
            }
            $results = getCueScores($testID);
            $results = getCongruencyScores($testID, $results);
            $alerting = $results["noCue"] - $results["doubleCue"];
            $orienting = $results["centerCue"] - $results["spatialCue"];
            $executive = $results ["incongruent"] - $results["congruent"];
            echo 'Your alerting result is' . $alerting;
            echo 'Your orienting result is' . $orienting;
            echo 'Your executive result is' . $executive;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

JS

```
        $(".btn[name=submitANT").click(function() {
        $.post("antApp.php",
            {response : $("input[name=rspStr]").val(), RT : $("input[name=RTStr]").val(), nTrial : $("input[name=nTrial]").val(), toa : $("input[name=toa]").val(),
            condition : $("input[name=condition]").val(), ansStr : $("input[name=ansStr]").val(), cueStr : $("input[name=cueStr]").val(),
            congruency : $("input[name=congruency]").val()},
            function(data) {
                //$("#antDebrief").show();
                //$("#antDebrief").css("visibility", "visible");
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does `addTest()` return? if it's not echo-ing, plain and simple it's not getting to it.

Comment: It returns the id of the previous sql insert, which I used again to retrieve the calculated values from the test

Comment: After opening: `if (isset($testID)) {` add `die("Yup, I made it into this if statement");` then run the script again.

Comment: The mysql inserts don't work now when I use that. The inserts still worked with the echo statements, but didn't print anything out.

Comment: I don't understand why the mysql function addTest() works if it wasn't getting to it. That function shouldn't be called if that was the case

Comment: Okay, so it makes it into the if statement. Can you confirm that both: `$results = getCueScores($testID);` and `$results = getCongruencyScores($testID, $results);` are returning the correct values and not terminating the script due to syntax errors etc. One of them must be failing for the "impossible to fail" `echo` functions to not be called

Comment: I just commented those functions out, and wrote an echo before and after addResponse(), and still nothing prints. The data is clearly being added to my database, as I'm always checking for new records. The JQuery post method made the page not refresh, and I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the echo not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You PHP sends `header('Location: index.php');` right after the echos.

This is like a `window.location.href="XYZ";`.
It redirects the page.
So maybe there is nothing wrong but you just don't have the time to see the echos.

Try commenting this line :

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

**EDIT** based on comment

**1-** Your "calling" page has to be different than the "called" page. A page that calls itself is never a good thing.

**2-** in your called page (antApp.php), the header is present : `require_once 'php-includes/header.php';` and this is probably the body and footer : `include ('php-includes/phpValidate.php');`

Comment: Even when I remove that same thing, sadly.

Comment: adding this: $('#antDebrief').html(data) inside function(data) solved the echo problem, but now this prints the same page twice on the screen. This means two headers, footers and main body.

Comment: **1-** Your "calling" page has to be different than the "called" page. A page that calls itself is never a good thing. **2-** in your called page (antApp.php), the header is present : `require_once 'php-includes/header.php';` and this is probably the body and footer : `include ('php-includes/phpValidate.php');`

Comment: I solved this problem, and you are right! I put the post script in a new page and the results echo on screen.

Comment: Great... So I'll update my answer with my last comment... Then you could accept it. ;)